# cordova.js for android phonegap application

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

I am developing android app , but i can't able to find cordova.js  to detect events . Please help me in finding this ?  I tried  on google code base , but they did not work .

Comment: are you going to develop a phonegap app? Have you downloaded (cordova.js) it from phopnegap.

Comment: hi , sorry i don't see it any where , I installed and created my app folder  via  node.js . I don't see any  cordova.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phonegap build CLI utility (which I find is the easiest way), then you don't need to include the cordova.js or phonegap.js files manually in the www directory in the project as they are added by the phonegap build utility automatically.

You do need to add the following though in all html files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

As far as phonegap functionality is concerned, you might need to instal some plugins as described [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

For example if you want to add the accelerometer functionality you would have to enter the following command while in the phonegap project directory:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device-motion.git
```

Comment: hi thanks for this ,  I downloaded git , and set up the path ..  now I am able to add the plugins , I am not use how to use git . but i did some research  .. Thanks alot man  :)