# Dreamweaver CC and cordova.js

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

This is my first time building an Android app and I'm using Dreamweaver CC and PhoneGap Build. When you start building an app from scratch Dreamweaver adds in all the necessary jQuery files but doesn't include a cordova.js file. My first question is do I need to include it in my build? Second question is when I try to include the latest version of the cordova.js file I get 4 live view prompt boxes coming up with:

```
gap:["PluginManager","startup","PluginManager703133838"]
gap:["Device","getDeviceInfo","Device703133839"]
gap:["NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo","NetworkStatus703133840"]
gap:["App","show","App703133841"]
```

[image]

Anyone know what they mean?

Comment: @MesserIf you want to upload pics send me a dropbox link i ll upload it here for you :D

Comment: @dakshshah thank you! They all look like this one http://www.mediafire.com/view/l9pt6jdfcizztng/Screen_shot_2014-02-28_at_15.53.44.png

Comment: 1. I uploaded your photo :D 2. I wrote an answer, read it and if it satisfies your needs kindly put a tick besides it. 3. Welcome to stackoverflow! 4. Always take care about one thing in mind before asking a question here that you have to first search for an answer yourself or try somethings yourself and then ask, and also include what you have tried to solve the problem and don't get scared :D :) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `cordova.js` is necessary when you build through PhoneGap and in that too, you do not need to add the `cordova.js` manually it is auto-generated when you ran the PhoneGap create script.

If you are using phonegap build CLI utility (which I find is the easiest way), then you don't need to include the cordova.js or phonegap.js files manually in the www directory in the project as they are added by the phonegap build utility automatically.

You do need to add the following though in all html files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

As far as phonegap functionality is concerned, you might need to instal some plugins as described [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

For example if you want to add the accelerometer functionality you would have to enter the following command while in the phonegap project directory:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device-motion.git
```

You may also want to have a look [here](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/21/introducing-cordova-js/).

**Sources:**
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358968/cordova-js-for-android-phonegap-application), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986645/phonegap-startup-do-we-need-all-those-files)