# Missing cordova.js and Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined

Tags: android, cordova

So I have created an from scratch app using the latest version of Cordova and followed the instructions from the Cordova API documentation. I am trying to get a very basic mp3 player working on Android, so I have installed the Android platform and installed the Media and Device plugins through the CLI. I am also using the full example of a media player from the API documentation. My code at the moment looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("https://ia600808.us.archive.org/21/items/NasaAudioHighlightReels/Launch-Sound_STS-1-Launch.mp3");
    }

    // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    //
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    //
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    //
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('https://ia600808.us.archive.org/21/items/NasaAudioHighlightReels/Launch-Sound_STS-1-Launch.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have build the app in the CLI and then run it with Chrome Developer and I'm getting 2 errors, 1) the cordova.js file cannot be found and 2) Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined.

I know that when the Android platform is added the cordova file is located in the platform_www folder but how do I link to that folder? I've tried coping the cordova.js to the main www folder but every time I do get the messages that are descriped in this link [Dreamweaver CC and cordova.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100000/dreamweaver-cc-and-cordova-js)

This is driving nuts so if anyone can shed some light on the problem it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't test the app with Chrome developer - you have to run it on an emulator or device. This is why you are getting the `cordova.js file not found` which will in turn generate the other issue about missing the Media plugin. You should run the app on a device or emulator - with Android 4.4 you can use Chrome:Inspect to access some Chrome developer tools through the devices' WebView.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but just want to make sure you remember to add the URL to your mp3 file to the whitelist.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have build and installed the app onto my phone using PhoneGap Build and the mp3 player still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I think your code run fine. If you want to testing using your browser, you need to use ripple chrome extension to run in mobile environment. You will got this error message if you not run the app in mobile environment.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
```

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en